# Creating exe vcxproj in Win 7 SP 1: The procedure entry point <function> could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNAL32.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64, kernel32, vcxproj

"The procedure entry point CreateFile2 could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNAL32.dll"

We have been going to a new system, C++ built by waf to a Visual Studio 2013 build(vcxproj), converted several projects already but they all build to dlls.  Trying to build an external exe file project has been a bit more difficult.  At first it wasn't even seeing it as a win32 app (though I'm building in x64) but I added:

```
<IsLauncher>true</IsLauncher>
```

Which seemed to fix that.  Now I'm getting that above error.

I am using an old 3rd party plugin that has a logic path that uses CreateFile2.  I have the windows 8.1 kit already installed on my machine(for some reason) and it's trying to use the windows.h from it.  I tried including the Windows SDK\7.1A for it's windows.h which defines it correctly but the sal_supp.h defined macros that VS 2013's sal.h also defined, an unworking solution.

I reviewed other questions but they all seem to be issues with Win XP, nothing on Windows 7 that totally fit.  And since this deals with Kernel32 most other questions don't seem to deal with system dlls or creating your own vcxproj.  This all worked when I build it in waf so I know it isn't actually anything wrong with anything installed.

Stuff I've tried:

```
<ClCompile><PreprocessorDefinitions>WINVER=0x0601;_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601;WIN32;_MBCS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions></ClCompile>

<PropertyGroup Label="Configuration"><UseOfMfc>Dynamic</UseOfMfc></PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup><LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental></PropertyGroup>

<Link><AdditionalDependencies>kernel32.lib;Ws2_32.lib;psapi.lib;zlib.lib;shlwapi.lib;...</AdditionalDependencies></Link>
```

I know, not a linker error but it was worth a try.

Comment: It is at the bottom of the MSDN article, "Minimum supported client".  8 > 7.  Applying the two-by-four: do **not** target Windows version 10 when you want you program to run on Window 7.

Comment: Sorry originally I thought this computer was running Windows 10 so I had WINVER=0x0A00.

So it turns out that the reason the code logic is trying to run Windows 8 code is that the system has Windows Kits 8.1 installed and was using their windows.h.  I tried to change it to Windows SDK\7.1A's windows.h but it has a sal_supp.h with defines macros that are also defined in VS 12.0's sal.h.  Leaving me in a different broken state.

Answer (score 0):

The [CreateFile2 function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422(v=vs.85).aspx) was added in Windows 8, so you can't use it if you still need Windows 7 compatibility.

> **Minimum supported client** Windows 8 [desktop apps | Windows Store apps]

Comment: The 3rd Party code has logic blocking it from being used in windows that don't have it but as I stated above in the comment, Windows Kit 8.1 is installed and it's trying to use the windows.h from it.  Windows SDK\7.1A also doesn't work with VS 2013 it seems.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateFile2` was introduced in Windows 8. The main reason to use it is so that a library or DLL will pass WACK when used in a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app which won't allow `CreateFile`. A good way to code this for C++ is:

```
struct handle_closer { void operator()(HANDLE h) { if (h) CloseHandle(h); } };

typedef public std::unique_ptr<void, handle_closer> ScopedHandle;

inline HANDLE safe_handle( HANDLE h ) { return (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ? 0 : h; }

#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
        ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(CreateFile2(fileName,
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            nullptr)));
#else
        ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(CreateFileW(fileName,
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            nullptr,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            nullptr)));
#endif
        if (!hFile)
        {
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
        ...
```

The problem here is if you try to build this code with an older Windows 7.1 SDK or earlier because `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8` is not defined so you end up taking the first case even when you don't want to. If you are going to support building this code in contexts other than the Windows 8.x SDK or Windows 10 SDK, you should go with this instead:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0602 /*_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8*/)
```

Comment: Thanks, if it wasn't 3rd Party code I'd permanently use that(it does provide a temp fix for now).  They do have logic to keep it from being used but as I've commented above Windows Kits 8.1 is installed and the windows.h in it is being used.  I tried using the Windows SDK 7.1A windows.h but it tried to redefine macros in VS 2013's sal.h.